# express Pochhammer symbol $(x)_n$ as a polynomial of order $n$ in $x$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Define 
$$(x)_{n}=x(x-1)(x-2)...(x-n+1)=\prod_{k=1}^{n} (x-k+1)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$$

**Q:** what is the closed-form expression for $a_k$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x^{\underline n}=\sum_k(-1)^{n-k}{n\brack k}x^k\;,$$

where I use my preferred notation for the falling factorial (Pochhammer symbol), and $n\brack k$ is a [Stirling number of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).

Comment: @mike: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

It is just (better use Knuth's notation):
$$
x^{\underline{n}} = \sum_{k \ge 0} (-1)^{n - k} \genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{}{n}{k} x^k
$$
Here $\displaystyle \genfrac{[}{]}{0pt}{}{n}{k}$ are [Stirling numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number) of the first kind.

To prove this, derive a recurrence for the coefficients and check it agrees with the one for the Stirling numbers.